# Retrieveing eth0 ipv6 address on linux

Tags: linux, scripting, ip-address, ipv6, ifconfig

I'm looking to use my eth0 ipv6 address in one of my shell scripts. I could retrieve it using ifconfig and grep, but I'm certain that it must be somewhere in some text file I'm not seeing, which would ultimately make it much easier to retrieve. Anyone know where I should look?

Thanks

Comment: No, it's not in a text file. The property of the eth** interface which is indeed stored in a config text file is its MAC address, but that's not the IP address.

Comment: The MAC address is `/sys/class/net/eth0/address`, to be exact. But the IP{,v6} addresses are nowhere to be seen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ip addr show eth0 | awk '/inet6/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: you are an amazing individual